# cannot get subset of date from df based on date columns

Tags: r, dplyr, boolean, posixct, as.date

I am making a report about a data frame containing transactions for parking. The data frame has two POSIXct variables called **start_time** and **end_time**. An example of how they look is this:

`2019-11-25 10:35:00 UTC" "2019-11-28 18:21:00 UTC"`

I want to get a subset of my data frame from `"2020-02-06"` till `"2020-03-23"`.
There are definitely transactions that occurred during this time but when I use the following code I get a subset with zero observations.

```
cutdate<- as.Date("2020-03-23",format ="%Y-%m-%d")
bdate<-as.Date("2020-06-02",format ="%Y-%m-%d")

dwdf%>% filter(as.Date(start_time) >= bdate & as.Date(end_time) < cutdate)->Bdf
```

I have tried other functions like subset and so forth but I get the same thing. I then tried something simpler and tried to see if from the variable **start_time** if I created a simple boolean expression like

```
any(as.Date(dwdf$start_time) > bdate)
```

If I would get any TRUE's but all I get is *false*. I do not understand why this is the case because if I do `range(start_time)` 
There are clearly start times that are later than february 6th.

I have also looked at similar questions on stack exchange and I don't know why I am getting different results since I am implementing what they said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend the `lubridate` package for dealing with time data.

```
library(lubridate)

x <- c("2019-11-25 10:35:00 UTC", "2019-11-28 18:21:00 UTC")

x_datetime <- ymd_hms(x)

x_datetime < ymd(20191126)
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

These functions (`ymd` as in "year-month-day" or `ymd_hms` as in year-month-day-hour-minute-second") make it easy to convert the data into date formats. And once you have this, comparisons are not that hard.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I tried out the functions that you mentioned above and they work great. I just had a question though to your  answer. Why do you have the variable ```x_datetime ``` but I don't see you using it anywhere

Comment: You're absolutely right. That was a mistake and I corrected it.

Comment: By the way - if the answer is correct, mark it as the answer, so others know it works.